# To Show a ViewGroup only during a certain orientation

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android

I am to build some kind of a News App where there is a list of News. When tapped, detailed news should be shown.
 1. If the phone was in Portrait, the details are shown in another activity
 2. If the phone was in Landscape, the details are shown alongside the news list in the details layout fragment in the same activity.

(there is a fragment of 'News List' and of 'Details')

What i cannot accomplish is to get rid of the space the Details fragment would take - if i were in Landscape mode - in the Portrait mode.

This is because i have mentioned two empty viewGroups as container of the fragments in the activity layout file.

I don't want to make a separate layout for each orientation.

Is there a way to hide or thin out a viewgroup if it is empty?

Relevant Codes:

Main Activity xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/news_list_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        >
        </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        >
        </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity class - adding fragments according to my orientation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get orientation first
        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==1) { //portrait

            NewsList_fragment newsFrag = new NewsList_fragment(); //init any fragments that may be used

            FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager(); //prepare fragment manager
            FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();

            // Add fragments using fTransaction and then commit
            fTransaction.add(R.id.news_list_container, newsFrag);
            fTransaction.commit();
            }

        else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==2) { //landscape

            NewsList_fragment newsFrag = new NewsList_fragment(); //init any fragments that may be used
            Details_fragment detailsFrag = new Details_fragment();


            FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager(); //prepare fragment manager
            FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();

            // Add fragments using fTransaction and then commit
            fTransaction.add(R.id.news_list_container, newsFrag);
            fTransaction.add(R.id.details_container, detailsFrag);

            fTransaction.commit();
            }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I solved my problem with 
details_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Thanks to anyone who showed their concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to set the visibility of the layout containing the details fragment to View.GONE. View.GONE implies that the layout is invisible and does not take space. View.INVISIBLE means the view is just invisible but the space is still taken.

```
LinearLayout detailsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.details_container);
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration.orientation;
if (orientation == 1) // means orientations is portrait
    detailsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```